# How to lock a screen programmatically in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

hi i need help that how we can lock a mobile screen programmatically in xamarin.I have tried all the java code and  converted it in c# but nothing works

Comment: would something like turning screen off work?

Comment: yes i need to turn screen off too

Comment: Did you mean the java codes worked, but C# not?